# Method not found in Web API 2

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to figure out how to use Web API. I have gone through some tutorials and now Im trying to set up my web service. 
I have a really hard time trying to figure out why it cant find my methods. To me it just seems like random (the tutorials worked fine). 
During my experiments sometimes the get method returns "method not allowed".

This is my service:

```
public class ContentFilesController : ApiController
{
  [Route("api/contentfile/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetContentFiles(int count)
    {
        if (_contentFiles == null)
            GenerateContentFileList();
        List<ContentFile> files = new List<ContentFile>();
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            ContentFile cf = _contentFiles[i];
            if(!_filesOutForProcessing.Contains(cf))
            {
                files.Add(cf);
                i++;
            }
            if (i == count)
                break;
        }
        return Ok(files);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/contentfile/{files}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] List<ContentFile> files)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

}

Edit:
This is the code I am using to call the service:

```
static async Task TestAsync()        {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())            {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:46015/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/contentfile/1");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var contentfiles = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ContentFile>>();                    
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task ReportTest()
    {
        List<ContentFile> files = new List<ContentFile>()
        {
            new ContentFile(){Path="hej"},
            new ContentFile(){Path="då"}
        };

        using(var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:46015");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<List<ContentFile>>("api/contentfile", files);
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Where do you start looking? 
Im going crazy here.

Thanks!

Edit: to clarify the error, the problem with both client methods are that the  HttpResponseMessage has response.IsSuccessStatusCode false and the StatusCode = MethodNotAllowed or MethodNotFound.

Comment: put code form where you are calling this Api

Comment: I was unable to post the client code at the same time. I got an error when posting. 
But basically this is my client code:

Comment: still no code is there!

Comment: Is your client-side code running on the same domain (by this I mean, same host, same port - typically this means you are using the same project for your WebAPI and HTML front-end). If not, then this could be a [CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) issue - especially since you mentioned the 405 not allowed errors.

Comment: Im sorry, having a really hard time posting, I just keep getting "There was an error posting"

Comment: its ok no problem! you can try editing your question again!

Comment: @Erik83 - paste the new code into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or similar and comment here with the link, we'll try to edit in into your question.

Comment: Ok, I've placed the code on pastebin. 
This is the url: http://pastebin.com/PQHxtWFr
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: i guess you are really having hard time!! no url :O

Comment: Yeah, I must say, Chrome does not agree at all with stackoverflow. 
I've switched to Explorer now. That seems to help somewhat..

Comment: @Erik83 - OK I have edited that in for you. Although I would ask that you also provide us with some solid details on the errors, what line in the client-code they occur on, exception messages, etc. These are important for us to know :) Also, as this is not being called from a Browser, CORS is not the issue so ignore my previous.

Comment: Firstly... What methods? What errors? When are you getting this error? How are we supposed to help with this description of your problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry, well, there is no exception on either methods. Just that the HttpResponseMessage has a StatusCode that says: MethodNotAllowed or method not found. 
And that is all that happens...

Comment: @BenjaminPaul, sorry, I had problems with posting the client code here to I posted it on pastebin, this is the url:  pastebin.com/PQHxtWFr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Problems with the GET method

For the HTTP Get method, there is a problem with your routing.

You have declared the GET route as this:

```
[Route("api/contentfile/{id}")]
```

but then the method parameter is declared as this:

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetContentFiles(int count)
```

When using Attribute-based routing, the parameter *names* have to match.

I made a very simple reproduction of your code (obviously I don't have your classes but the infrastructure will be the same)

#### In the WebAPI project

```
public class ContentFile
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContentFilesController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/contentfile/{count}")] //this one works
        [Route("api/contentfile/{id}")] //this one does not work
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetContentFiles(int count)
        {
            var files = new List<ContentFile>();
            for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
            {
                files.Add(new ContentFile(){ID=x});
            }

            return Ok(files);
        }
    }
```

#### In the client project

```
public class ContentFile
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51518/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/contentfile/1").Result;
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

So the code is not quite identical to yours but it's pretty much the same code. Running the WebAPI project and then the client gives me:

`[{"ID":0}]`

### Problems with the POST method

In the case of the `POST` method, you are declaring a route parameter, but this is never sent as part of the route, it's a POST body:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/contentfile/{files}")] //{files} here tells routing to look for a parameter in the *Route* e.g api/contentfile/something
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] List<ContentFile> files)
```

So the simple fix is to remove `{files}` from the Route template for this one.

Hope this helps.